# Cropping Image(From Screen)

Tags: c#, image, crop, system.drawing

I have read many question about this. But my question is little bit different. What i need to do crop image from screen.

There is my codes

```
Bitmap photo = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.primaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(photo);
gr.CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0 new size(foto.Width,foto.Height));
picturebox1.Image = photo;
```

And there my crop codes

```
Rectangle cropRec = new Rectangle(1,1,1,1);
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRec.Width,cropRec.Height);
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
g.DrawImage(photo,new Rentangle(0,0,target.Width,target.Height),cropRec,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

I want to crop middle part of this photo and compare with itself.
 Thanks n advance

Comment: What have you tried already, and what errors are you encountering?

Comment: I aded my codes. But how can i crop this middle from screen?

Answer (score 0):

To symmetrically crop your image as shown in the following [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpjOh.png), try creating a Bitmap with margins in the X and Y axis and then cropping the screenshot image by using those margins in CopyFromScreen():

```
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 2 * xmargin, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 2 * ymargin);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(xmargin, ymargin, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
```